# Are there any ways to modify the URL of web requests in webpages?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm viewing a third-party website. The webpage loads some images like https://heatmap-external-c.strava.com/tiles/both/bluered/12/1505/2306.png via JavaScript. However, the URLs no longer work and should be replaced by https://heatmap-external-c.strava.com/tiles-auth/both/bluered/12/1505/2306.png. (this is viewable if login)

Are there any ways to view the webpage correctly? (probably via a browser plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The tool to use on Firefox is
[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
to edit the web-page, or
for Chrome [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

Try this (untested) userscript:

```
var a = document.links;
var i;
for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)
  if (a[i].href.startsWith("https://heatmap-external-c.strava.com/tiles/both/bluered/12/"))
    a[i].href = a[i].href.replace("tiles","tiles-auth");
```

For more information about Greasemonkey, see the
[GreaseSpot website](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page).